# vue-class-component & Mixins

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-class-components

I use vue-class-component with TypeScript for my Vue project. I have the component and the Mixin for it:

```
// MyComp.vue
import Component, { mixins } from 'vue-class-component'
import MyMixin from './mixin.ts'

@Component
export class MyComp extends mixins(MyMixin) {
  compValue: string = 'Hello';
}


// mixin.ts
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

@Component
export default class MyMixin extends Vue {
  created() {
    console.log(this.compValue); // TS2339: Property 'compValue' does not exist on type 'MyMixin'.
  }
}
```

It works, but TypeScript complains about missing Property 'compValue'. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because `compValue` doesn't exist in `MyMixin`. In case this is abstract class that is never instantiated on its own and it's guaranteed the property is there, it can be declared:

```
export default class MyMixin extends Vue {
  compValue: string;
  created() {
    console.log(this.compValue);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use **mixins** you will inherit from a **class**. TypeScript is absolutely right, you have a mixin class that has a `created()` lifecycle not a prop. and in `MyComp` class you have a prop. if you were to switch what both classes contain then it would work, because you would be inherting the prop from the mixin.

like so:

```
// --- mixin.ts -----------------
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

@Component
export default class MyMixin extends Vue {
  compValue: string = 'Hello';
}

// --- MyComp.vue ---------------- 
import Component, { mixins } from 'vue-class-component'
import MyMixin from './mixin.ts'

@Component
export class MyComp extends mixins(MyMixin) {
created() {
    console.log(this.compValue); 
  }  

}
```